# Understand MIPI-CS2 camera connector on ZYBO Z7

Tags: differential

Please take a look at page 2 and page 11 of [this](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/reference/programmable-logic/zybo-z7/zybo_z7_sch-public.pdf) datasheet. Why do they bridge the MIPI signals of the connector J2 with a 150R resistor and connect the signals with the FPGA and additional connect each of the terminals of the 150R resistor over a 100R resistor with the FPGA?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Transmission line balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the recommended D-PHY termination for the Xilinx I/O pins for both high-speed and LP modes.

Xilinx uses separate pins for the LVDS differential signals and the LP single-ended signals. They fixed this with the Ultrascale parts, but the regular series 7 needs this setup.

More here: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Video/MIPI-CSI2-D-PHY-to-FPGA-Zynq/td-p/903883

Comment: Thank you for the link. Do I have to use the LP lines or can I use the differential pairs only?

Comment: It depends on the camera you intend to support. It's better to include it.